# Expectation of the product of two correlated normal variables

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, expected-value, lognormal-distribution

Let two independent normal variables $X\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2).$ Let $Z=e^X+e^Y.$ Then $Z$ is lognormal random variable. Is it possible to calculate  $\mathbf E[X\times \log(Z)]?$

Comment: In any actual situation, simulation will get you a reasonable approximation

Comment: $Z$, the sum of two lognormal distributed variables, is not (exactly) lognormal.

Comment: Z can be approximated by a log-normal random variable :) Then, \log(Z) can be approximated by a normal one